# Cannot access cms panel in the same network

Tags: networking, apache2, browser, webserver, cms

I have installed and configured [neos cms](https://www.neos.io/download-and-extend.html) on an ubuntu machine on my network.
The problem is that I cannot access the cms control panel or website from another pc on the network.
The link I should type in the browser is 192.168.1.8:8081 but it gives me an 'Unable to connect' error.
On the other hand I am capable of accessing the apache index.html file.
What could be the problem?

Comment: probably your config can you access 192.168.1.8:8081 on the host PC itself?

Comment: No, I cannot access it even from the host pc. Only by going to localhost or 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Errr wait so it works as 127.0.0.1:8081 but not 192.168.1.8:8081?

1. Confirm that IP is correct with `ipconfig -all`
2. If IP is correct your app is probably only configured to listen on local interface. Confirm that with `netstat -an | grep 8081` if you see `127.0.0.1:8081` than that's the case. Edit app configs to listen on correct interface/s

Comment: The IP address is correct, I have double checked that. With netstat -an it shows indeed 127.0.0.1:8081 as Local Address and 0.0.0.0:* as Foreign Address.

Comment: There ya go, only your PC can access 127.x.x.x network. The app should be listening on 0.0.0.0:8081 or 192.168.1.8:8081 for others have access to it. It's a security feature so  you don't open it up to your whole network by default. Look at your configs